# convert char to int using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm new  to Regular Expressions. I'm trying to identify the year in

```
vsdir
```

as an integer e.g. number (2013) where

```
vsdir="vs2013"
```

so that I can apply an if statement where if this number is < 2010 (one outcome), else (another outcome)

I'm doing this in a pythpon script. Can anyone give any suggestions please?

Comment: Why do you think you need regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this,

```
if int(vsdir[-4:]) < 2010:
    print("yeh, less tha 2010")
else:
    print("greater than 2010")
```

OR

```
if int(re.search(r'\d+',vsdir).group()) < 2010:
    print("yeh, less tha 2010")
else:
    print("greater than 2010")
```